# How can I change the default reminder time in outlook for me, personally?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

Per the question, I want to be able to change how much time outlook gives *me* before a meeting.

I see the "default reminder time" but everything I see indicates that for when creating new appointments -- not when accepting.  Testing this proves that that's the case.

I want the little pop-up to show 5 minutes prior regardless what the appointment creator set.  How can I do this (if I even can)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid there is no built-in option available in Outlook to accomplish this. By design the incoming appointments will override the default reminder time set via Options. As a workaround, you may have to manually change the reminder per event.

Comment: There seems to be several UserVoice requests for it but this one has the most votes - unfortunately just for Mac: https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/293343-outlook-for-mac/suggestions/31817122-allow-the-default-snooze-time-for-calendar-reminde